# Provide a better access to the favourite tags

Tags: feature-request, user-interface, tag-watching

On the [main SO page](http://stackoverflow.com), favourite tags are on top of the page with easy access :
[image]

But selecting anything, this list goes way down, and is not easily selectable (requires scrolling down).

For selected questions :
[image]

For selected tag :
[image]

How about putting favourite tags on top of the page? The way it is done in the 1st image.

Comment: Why not just hide the ads altogether, eh?

Comment: I guess owners of SO has to earn some money, no? :P Seriously, it would be good to have a better access to favourite tags

Comment: Protip:  [crop](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cropping_(image))